# How to get lisbox.SelectedIndex to work with multiple items selected on multiple list boxes?

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I am creating a series of list boxes that I want to click on the first item and in the first list box and it loads the items in list box 2. Then when I click on an item in list box 2 it loads items in list box 3.  When I click on items in list box one, list box 2's items load but when I click on items in list box 2 to load list box 3 nothing loads and I don't get an error.  Not sure why this code is not working when it works for list box 1?

```
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && !listBox2.Items.Contains("Directory50        >"))
        {
            if (listBox2.Items.Count >= 5)
            {
                for (int i = listBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // do with listBox1.Items[i]

                    listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add("Directory5" + x.ToString() + "        >");
            }

            if (listBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {///I get no response here from listbox2 when mouse clicking the first item in listbox2
                for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add("Directory51" + x.ToString() + ".txt");
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0
```

OR

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 (-1 if first item needs to load something)

listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 // means nothing selected

// means an item selected and first item is with index = 0 
listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 or 1 or 2 ... etc
```

Comment: I'm sorry were you talking about listBox1.SelectedIndex or listBox2.SelectedIndex because listBox2.SelectedIndex is where I get the error.

Comment: Both have the same issue and needs this info to be into consideration and code based on it